# Dockerfile manual install of multiple deb files

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, deb

Working with Docker and I notice almost everywhere the "RUN" command starts with an apt-get upgrade && apt-get install etc.

What if you don't have internet access and simply want to do a "dpkg -i ./deb-directory/*.deb" instead?

Well, I tried that and I keep failing.  Any advice would be appreciated:

```
  dpkg: error processing archive ./deb-directory/*.deb (--install):
  cannot access archive: No such file or directory
 Errors were encountered while processing: ./deb-directory/*.deb
 INFO[0002] The command [/bin/sh -c dpkg -i ./deb-directory/*.deb] returned a non-zero code: 1`
```

To clarify, yes, the directory "deb-directory" does exist.  In fact it is in the same directory as the Dockerfile where I build.

Comment: Please post your Dockerfile, maybe you need to *ADD* the deb File ?

Comment: That is not an ideal solution, if I have 85 deb files I want to install, do I need to ADD 85 times?

Comment: ADD can also copy a directory not only files, so you dont need to copy 85 files. But anyway its easier if you post your Dockerfile or a minimal example like an ubuntu and one deb file, so someone/we can reproduce and learn from your error.

Comment: The Docker file is only required to build containers. Connect the build machine to the internet and built images will work fine without an externel network.

Comment: it doesn't directly answer your question, but an apt repo would solve all your issues here, assuming your packages have their dependencies right and all that.

Answer (score 8):

This is perhaps a bug, I'll open a ticket on their github to know.
**Edit:** I did it [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10735).

**Edit2:**
Someone answered a better way of doing this on the github issue.

> `*` is a shell metacharacter. You need to invoke a shell for it to be expanded.
>
> `docker run somecontainer sh -c 'dpkg -i /debdir/*.deb'`

**!!! Forget the following but I leave it here to keep track of my reflexion steps !!!**

The problem comes from the `*` statement which doesn't seem to work well with the `docker run dpkg` command. I tried your command inside a container (using an interactive shell) and it worked well. It looks like `dpkg` is trying to install the so called `./deb-directory/*.deb` file which doesn't exist instead of installing all the `.deb` files contained there.

I just implemented a workaround. Copy a `.sh` script in your container, `chmod +x` it and then use it as your command.
(FYI, prefer using `COPY` instead of `ADD` when the file isn't remotely copied. Check [the best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) for more info.)

This is my Dockerfile for example purpose:

```
FROM debian:latest
MAINTAINER Vrakfall <jeremy@artphotolaurent.be>

COPY install.sh /
#debdir is a directory
COPY debdir /debdir
RUN chmod +x /install.sh

CMD ["/install.sh"]
```

The `install.sh` (copied at the root directory) simply contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
dpkg -i /debdir/*.deb
```

And the following

```
docker build -t debiantest .
docker run debiantest
```

works well and install all the packages contained in the `/debdir` directory.